# How to install WordPress on Linux without root privileges?

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I am trying to install WordPress locally on a server using the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04). Because I do not have root privileges on the server, I have asked the admin to create a SQL database for me. Additionally, because the installation is local, I cannot move the downloaded `wordpress` directory to `/var/www/html`.

Theere is a website associated with the server `www.our_server.university.edu` and each user can create his/her own website on `www.our_server.university.edu/~user`.

When I get to the last step of installation, which is through the Web interface, I get an error saying that I do not have permission to access the website. I suspect that this is because I have not put my directory under `/var/www/html`. If that is in fact the reason, how can I have a local wordpress directory without copying it to `var/www/html`?

Comment: Usually on this config, there's a `~/Public` folder on your home. I will start testing with a `index.html` or `index.php` file there, and calling `http://www.our_server.university.edu/~user/index.html`

Comment: I used to have a public_html directory under my home and it worked well with my previous website. Can I put WordPress directories under the same directory?

Comment: you could use something like `~/public_html/blog/` and install wordpress there. The only (maybe) tricky thing will be configuring the path on wordpress, but if i remember correctly, that's part of the setup wizard.

Comment: Moving everything to `~/public_html` fixed the problem.

Comment: @Mahdi, please write an answer and describe the solution you've found. Then you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `var/www/html` is not `/var/www/html`:

- `var/www/html` will be your current folder + var/www/html like `/home/myuser/var/www/html`
- `/var/www/html` will be really this folder

Probably it's just a mistypo, but wanted to check this with you cause it's easy to do this kind of failure.

Are you able to find an error number? Like 500? It could be related to a missing apache module. Can you check apache error logs (probably in `/var/log/apache2`)?

Comment: I created /var/www/html under my user's home directory, but I still get the same error message. Unfortunately, no error message is printed

Comment: Did you checked apache error logs? For sure it will show the exact error you have and by copying it here we will be able to give you a solution :).
Take a look here: /var/log/apache2

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the directory you mentioned. I should ask admin to find the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I followed bistoco's answer and placed all wordpress contents under `~/public_html` directory and it solved the problem.